# Horizontal ScrollView inside Vertical RecyclerView inside Horizontal RecyclerView scrolling behavior

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have an `Activity` below:

```
<RecyclerView> // with horizontal LinearLayoutManager and PagerSnapHelper
    <RecyclerView> // with vertical LinearLayoutManager
        <RecyclcerView /> // with horizontal LinearLayoutManager
        <HorizontalScrollView />
        // ... and there are other normal list items
    </RecyclerView>
    <RecyclerView> // another RV with vertical LinearLayoutManager
    </RecyclerView>
</RecyclerView>
```

The problem is when I scroll horizontally, the inner horizontal `RecyclerView` and `HorizontalScrollView` doesn't scroll as expected.

**Why I have to do this:**

I have several `ListFragment`s, each of which takes data from different data sources, but has same type of list items. I don't want a `ViewPager`, which either hold all pages immediately after `ViewPager` is created(which may cause OutOfMemoryError), or reload data from network after user scrolling to other pages and scroll back. Further more, with nested RV, pages can share one same `RecyclerViewPool`, which helps to decrease total count of item views in all pages.

**What I have done in the outer horizontal RV:**

```
private static final int INVALID_POINTER = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
private float lastX;
private GestureDetector mVerticalScrollGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return Math.abs(distanceX) < Math.abs(distanceY);
    }
});
private GestureDetector mHorizontalScrollGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY);
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (mVerticalScrollGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e) || !mAllowPageScroll) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mActivePointerId = e.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int pointerIndex = e.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            float x = e.getX(pointerIndex);
            float dx = x - lastX;
            lastX = x;
            if (childCanScroll(this, false, (int) dx, (int) x)) {
                Log.d("ScrollX", "not intercept");
                return false;
            }
            Log.d("ScrollX", "maybe intercept");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
}

private boolean childCanScroll(View v, boolean considerSelf, int dx, int x) {
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) v;
        int scrollX = v.getScrollX();
        for (int i = group.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (x + scrollX >= child.getLeft() && x + scrollX < child.getRight()
                    && childCanScroll(child, true, dx, x + scrollX - child.getLeft())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return considerSelf && v.canScrollHorizontally(-dx);
}
```

Now it works with inner horizontal RV with **occasionally not scrolling**, and **doesn't work with `HorizontalScrollView` at all**.

How can I achieve the goal to make inner horizontally-scrollable view to scroll first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes I make.

1. In case of `ACTION_DOWN` I need to record the `lastX` variable as well as in case of `ACTION_MOVE`, so that first move of `dx` is a proper value. This explains why the `childCanScroll` method doesn't work on things like `ScrollView`(as `RecyclerView`'s `getScrollX()` always return 0).
2. In method `childCanScroll`, the inner `if` statement should not only consider the x coordinate, but also the y coordinate. If y is not considered, when I scroll outside inner horizontal-scrollable-views, the method also return `true`, that make things not working properly.

After I fix these two mistakes all things are right.

Comment: Could you please put this code again after fixing?

Comment: @WaelYoussef  It's a project from my former company, so I have no access to that code now. Sorry :(